# Can't use template variable of type string where a string literal would be allowed?

Tags: hugo

It seems I cannot invoke `.Resources.GetMatch` with a template variable of type string, though I can invoke it with a string literal.  I know I can invoke it with `.` in a `with` block, but would like to know why this code doesn't work.

Main template invokes partial with a second argument stuffed into `.Scratch`:

```
single.html
...html
<div >
    <p>Feature image:</p>
    {{ .Scratch.Set "arg1" .Params.image}}
    {{ partial "local-image.html" . }}
    <p>End feature image:</p>
  </div>
```

Partial tries to retrieve the scratch argument and retrieve the corresponding page resource object:

```html
{{ $srcPath := (.Scratch.Get "arg1") }}
{{ printf "debug type %T, value %#v" $srcPath $srcPath}}
{{ .Resources.GetMatch $srcPath }}
```

Hugo build error:

```
ERROR 2020/11/24 00:28:34 Failed to render pages: render of "page" failed: 
execute of template failed: template: _default/single.html:67:7: executing "main" at <partial "local-image.html" .>: 
error calling partial: "C:\Users\xyz\src\hugo-blog\themes\hugo-theme-bootstrap4-blog\layouts\partials\local-image.html:5:23": execute of template failed: 
template: partials/local-image.html:5:23: executing "partials/local-image.html" at <$srcPath>: 
invalid value; expected string
```

If I comment out the failing line so I can see the preceeding debug output,

```html
{{ $srcPath := (.Scratch.Get "arg1") }}
{{ printf "debug type %T, value %#v" $srcPath $srcPath}}
{{/* .Resources.GetMatch $srcPath */}}
```

Build succeeds, and page renders this:

```
Feature image:

debug type string, value "IMG_20200404_164934.jpg"
End feature image:
```

So the puzzle here is why `.Resources.GetMatch` complains about `$srcPath` when the latter is demonstrably of type `string`.

(Yes, I know it would be more colloquial to pass multiple arguments into a partial in a `dict`, but I was running into similar errors extracting values out in the partial, so came up with the above more concise example.)

Comment: Does it work if you pass the string value? `{{ .Resources.GetMatch "IMG_20200404_164934.jpg" }}`

Comment: ...yes... (padding characters)

Comment: Your template should work as intended, maybe post on the hugo site as a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my problematic code and came up with a workable solution, but I never did discover exactly where I was going wrong above (it remains reproducible for anyone who would like to point out exactly where I did go wrong).

To close this thread with something like an acceptable answer, here's what I did.
Maybe it will help some future wanderer...

Basically,

1. stuff all the arguments into a `dict` where the partial is invoked.
2. at the top of the partial, save value of `.` (e.g in a nicely-named local `$args` or `$argv`)
3. wherever you need a particular argument value, it's readily available in `$args.xyzzy`

I don't know why this simple and effective pattern eluded me yesterday, I see lots of similar suggestions around the web today...

```html
single.html
...html
<div >
    <p>Feature image:</p>
    {{ partial "local-image.html" (dict "page" . "arg1" .Params.image) }}
    <p>End feature image:</p>
  </div>
```

Then, to retrieve or use these arguments in the partial:

```html
{{ $args := . }}
. . .
{{ $srcPath := $args.arg1 }}
{{ printf "debug type %T, value %#v" $srcPath $srcPath}}
{{ .Resources.GetMatch $srcPath }}
```

Build succeeds, and page renders this:

```
Feature image:

debug type string, value "IMG_20200404_164934.jpg"
"IMG_20200404_164934.jpg"
End feature image:
```

Q.E.D.